# Error in making a fetch call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to loop through the multiple properties in an array and how to use map function and display the multiple properties in an array to the webpage

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      booksLists:'',
      description: ''
   }
 }
  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('https://reactnd-books-api.udacity.com/books', { headers: { 
   'Authorization': 'whatever-you-want' }})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
       this.setState({booksLists: res})
   })
  }

    render() {
    let booksLists = this.state.booksLists;
    console.log(booksLists)

    return (
      <div className="App">
         <h2>My Reads</h2>
         <p></p>
       </div>
      );
  }
}
```

export default App;

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: Call `.map` on `booksLists` and in the return function print an element and access properties off of the book.

Comment: the array has various properties such as title ,description, authors and other properties i just want to loop over all the books and its properties and display the results to the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/XaRxyX)**
, or you can run the snippet below:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      booksLists: []
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("https://reactnd-books-api.udacity.com/books", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "whatever-you-want"
      }
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
      this.setState({booksLists: res.books});
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {booksLists} = this.state;
    const books = booksLists
      ? booksLists.map(book => <div className='panel panel-default col-xs-12'>
        <div className='panel-heading'>
          <h3>{book.title || 'not available'}</h3>
          <h5>{book.subtitle || 'not available'}</h5>
        </div>
        <div className='panel-body'>
          <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-xs-4'>
              <img className='img-responsive' src={book.imageLinks.smallThumbnail}/>
            </div>          
            <div className='col-xs-8'>
              <p>
                <strong>Authors: </strong>
                 {book.authors
                  ? book.authors.join(', ')
                  : 'not available'}</p>
              <p>
                <strong>Publisher: </strong>
                {book.publisher || 'not available'}</p>
              <p>
                <strong>Date of publication: </strong>
                {book.publishedDate || 'not available'}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-xs-12'>
              <p>{book.description || 'not available'}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>)
      : null;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>My Reads</h2>
        {books}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: A small doubt without creating a component how could i append all those into input box so that when i enter a search term it should display the book results

Comment: You could use this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/gxWZPp)**. I would recommend using the [Google Books Api](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/overview) if you want to build a nice book search engine. You can clone [my repo](https://github.com/dankreiger/google-books-redux) if you want to see a working example of the Google Books API with React.

Comment: thanks bro really it means a lot to me .again for sharing your knowledge...

Comment: hi bro i'm new to redux how to make the same fetch call using redux

Comment: I use redux for a book search in [this repo](https://github.com/dankreiger/google-books-redux) - I'm using axios to do the ajax, Redux uses actions, reducers, and components, so you might want to post another question if you want to get full help on redux. It's a lot more code, but it can be beneficial if you want to keep a global state in your app.

Comment: Hi bro i have a doubt how to display the objects by using the array value like this {Currently Reading: Array(2), Want to Read: Array(2), Read: Array(3)}. so i want to display the books by the value of currently reading is that possible

Comment: Sure - if you have an object like `var obj = {'Currently Reading': ['book 1', 'book 2'], 'Want to Read': ['book 3', 'book 4'], 'Read': ['book 5', 'book 6']}
`, you can use the `Currently Reading` attribute by using `obj['Currently Reading']`

Answer (score 0):

If your booklist is an object you could do something like the following:

```
   render() {

     let list = booklist.arrayName.map(function(book) {
        return <li key={book}>{book}</li>;
      });     

    return (
      <div className="App">
         <h2>My Reads</h2>
         <ul>{ booksLists }</ul>
       </div>
      );
  }
```

Firstly you should `map` over the bookLists array returning a jsx element and assigning this mapped array to a new variable. Generally for a list this will be an `li` element. Each item requires a key. You can then reference the values you want to display within the `li` element.

You can then reference the new variable in the return statement of the `render` method.

Comment: thanks for your feedback but have tried that it being stated that this.state.booksLists.map is not a function

Comment: @viky is `this.state.bookLists` an array?

Comment: no its and object and consists of an array and again has various objects in it

Comment: can you show what it looks like in your question? You can only `map` over arrays, not objects.

Comment: @viky updated the answer. Without seeing what the `bookLists` looks like I can only provide general guidance. If you could add this object to your question I can provide a proper answer.

Comment: thank you,
If an array consists of objects and each object has a different properties such as title, authors, pageCount and i want to display the description of all books

Comment: @viky show an example of what the object looks like in your question.